# CentOS - downgrade to the stable PHP version

Tags: centos, yum

I am running CentOS and using the remi repository for PHP.

I have just found out I am using the development version of PHP, even if I need the stable version:

```
PHP 5.3.4-dev (cli) (built: Oct  3 2010 10:57:19)
```

I think that is because the content of my /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo is:

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch
baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el5.$basearch/
        http://iut-info.univ-reims.fr/remirpms/el5.$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
failovermethod=priority

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/test-el5.$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

I mean, I left the [remi-test] section.

How can I downgrade to the latest stable version of PHP (5.3.3)?

I have tried to comment the [remi-test] section and run `yum update php` but this is the message:

```
No Packages marked for Update
```

Has anybody know how to do it, please?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the php packages through YUM

```
yum erase php-etc.etc.etc
```

So your system has no php...
Then just install the standard ones..

you can see them by

```
yum search php
```

Comment: Thanks. I still want to install the Remi one because it should be more updated, but not the development ones.

Answer (score 1):

Disable [remi-test], then install `yum-allowdowngrade` and use its features to downgrade your `php` and associated packages.

Comment: Really that works? cool.. ill try that out :D +1